# Cant get the policy Perl::Critic::Policy::Tics::ProhibitLongLines to work

Tags: perl, perl-critic

I have:

- Ubuntu 10.04
- Perlbrew 0.39
- Switched to Perl 5.12.3. with perlbrew
- Installed Perl::Critic and Perl::Critic::Tics with cpanm

my .perlcriticrc file :

```
severity = 1
only= 1

[CodeLayout::ProhibitHardTabs]
allow_leading_tabs = 0

[Perl::Critic::Policy::CodeLayout::RequireConsistentNewlines]

[Perl::Critic::Policy::Tics::ProhibitLongLines]
base_max = 120
hard_max = 130
pct_allowed = 5

[Perl::Critic::Policy::OTRS::RequireCamelCase]
```

The other policies function as expected but whenever a line is over the length definded by hard_max, i get the error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $min_width in numeric gt (>) at /home/birdy/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.3/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/String/Format.pm line 51.
Use of uninitialized value $replength in numeric gt (>) at /home/birdy/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.3/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/String/Format.pm line 51.
Use of uninitialized value $max_width in numeric gt (>) at /home/birdy/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.3/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/String/Format.pm line 56.
Use of uninitialized value $replength in numeric gt (>) at /home/birdy/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.3/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/String/Format.pm line 56.
Use of uninitialized value $replength in subtraction (-) at /home/birdy/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.3/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/String/Format.pm line 67.
Use of uninitialized value $min_width in subtraction (-) at /home/birdy/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.3/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/String/Format.pm line 67.
Use of uninitialized value $replacement in concatenation (.) or string at /home/birdy/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.3/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/String/Format.pm line 67.
```

Thanks for your time and if you need any additional information, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me.  I get the same warnings even if I completely ignore my `.perlcriticrc` file:

```
perlcritic -1 --noprofile mycode.pl
```

I am on perl 5.12.2.

You should [submit a bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Report.html?Queue=Perl-Critic-Tics) against [Perl::Critic::Tics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic%3a%3aTics).  I have checked the `Changes` files for both `Tics` and [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic), but I did not find anything relevant to `String::Format`.  Make sure you have recent versions of `Critic` and `Tics`.  I have the current `Tics` (0.006), but my `Critic` is a little outdated (1.111).

Comment: I have Tics (0.006) and Perl::Critic (1.117). I submitted a report: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=74896

Comment: I got the same error in openSUSE 12.1, so I guess it is a bug. I would upvote your answer but I need 15 reputation points for that. Thanks for you time toolic.